# Pagination in Headless WordPress with WPGraphQL

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, next.js, pagination

Currently in Wordpress i can load products on page paginattion to write in url like `page/2 page/3` etc

Now I try in my next.js application first counts all products and then display pagination and load products the same way by switch page  like 1 2 3 etc.

But what I see currently I can in wpgraphql pass only next page like:

```
query MyQuery {
  products(first: 25, after: "YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjMxOTQy") {
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
      endCursor
      startCursor
    }
    nodes {
      date
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me how can I  get finally result to possible pass page example 3 and then load products  in this page.

Here is my current code:

```
export const useProductsData = () => {
  const params = useParams()
  const { handle } = params;

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const fetchProductsData = async () => {
    const query = gql`
    query {
      products(where: { categoryIn: "${handle}", stockStatus: IN_STOCK }, first: 25) {
        nodes {
          id
          sku
          slug
          status
          name
          image {
            sourceUrl
          }
          ... on SimpleProduct {
            id
            name
            price
          }
          ... on VariableProduct {
            id
            name
            price
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `;
  


    try {
      const result = await fetchWooCommerceData(query);
      setProducts(result.products.nodes);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  // Call fetchProductData directly when the hook is invoked
  fetchProductsData();

  return { products, loading, error };
};
```

I found plugin:
https://github.com/valu-digital/wp-graphql-offset-pagination

But looks like this above working only for users and posts.

I try register for products:

```
 // Register offsetPagination fields for WooCommerce products
    register_graphql_field(
        'RootQueryToProductConnectionWhereArgs',
        'offsetPagination',
        [
            'type' => 'OffsetPagination',
            'description' => 'Paginate products with offsets',
        ]
    );
}
```

Now when I query:

```
query Products {
  products(where: { offsetPagination: { size: 10, offset: 30 } }) {
    pageInfo {
      offsetPagination {
        hasMore
        hasPrevious
        total
      }
    }
    nodes {
      id
      name
      # Other product fields
    }
  }
}
```

I see output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "products": {
      "pageInfo": {
        "offsetPagination": {
          "hasMore": true,
          "hasPrevious": true,
          "total": 16300
        }
      },
      "nodes": [
```

but when i change page offset then still load the same products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Next.js code, you should manage the current page state and ensure that the fetchProductsData function uses this state to calculate the correct offset for the GraphQL query.

Here is a code you can try

```
export const useProductsData = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const { handle } = params;

  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const productsPerPage = 25;
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const fetchProductsData = async (page) => {
    const offset = (page - 1) * productsPerPage;
    const query = gql`
      query {
        products(where: { categoryIn: "${handle}", stockStatus: IN_STOCK, offsetPagination: { size: ${productsPerPage}, offset: ${offset} } }) {
          pageInfo {
            offsetPagination {
              hasMore
              hasPrevious
              total
            }
          }
          nodes {
            id
            sku
            slug
            status
            name
            image {
              sourceUrl
            }
            ... on SimpleProduct {
              id
              name
              price
            }
            ... on VariableProduct {
              id
              name
              price
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `;

    try {
      const result = await fetchWooCommerceData(query);
      setProducts(result.products.nodes);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProductsData(currentPage);
  }, [currentPage]);

  return { products, loading, error, setCurrentPage };
};
```